# Split a single video to multiple videos of equal intervals

Tags: python, ffmpeg, android-ffmpeg

**how to cut a video in regular intervals of time? Ex: if i am having a 30 minute video and have to cut it in 30 parts 1 min each, how to do it ? in ffmpeg**

Answer (score 0):

You could use the following tool (but I haven't tried it myself yet)
[Video splitter on github](https://github.com/c0decracker/video-splitter).

Below in the Readme you will find the area
"Splitting videos into unequal chunks".

You could either create the manifest.json or csv file manually or generate it in a simple python script and then run the tool with os.system or as a subprocess.